# Unable to put number in text box in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I want to put the number in the textbox and click on Get App link When I am using XPath[image]

command:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="ngdialog1"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("123456789");
```

When I run the script the popup window is opening but it does not enter the value in text box.
Please refer screenshot.

Comment: Try to wait until input field [become clickable](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits)

Comment: Added Thread.sleep(3000); but still it's not working

Comment: @kalpesh Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Thanks Debanjan, When i used the xpath for that textfield nd run the script, it does not identify the textfield and its not automatically fill the phone numbber.

Answer (score 0):

Add a wait, if necessary, as Andersson suggested, then use this xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(local-name(), 'input') and contains(@name, 'number')]")).sendKeys("123456789");
```

Comment: I have added wait and the given path but still it's unable to put value in textbox